# Mouse event animation in Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have added a button and added a BoxBlurEffect to it and set following attributes to the `BoxBlurEffect1`.

```
//extracted form fmx file 

object BoxBlurEffect1: TBoxBlurEffect
  Trigger = 'IsMouseOver=true'
  Enabled = False
  BlurAmount = 0.009999999776482582
  object FloatAnimation1: TFloatAnimation
    AnimationType = atInOut
    Enabled = True
    Duration = 1.000000000000000000
    Loop = True
    Trigger = 'IsMouseOver=true'
    TriggerInverse = 'IsMouseOver=false'
    StartValue = 0.009999999776482582
    StopValue = 10.000000000000000000
    PropertyName = 'BlurAmount'
  end
end
```

I set loop = true because if it is false it is not animating it is just suddenly going to end value.

So I set it to true. But now it is looping (as the name described) not just animating once and stopping.

And also I want it to animate from stop value to start value when I leave the mouse (only once). When my mouse leaves or enters, the new animation must start from current value not from the max or min value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trigger doesn't always work as I expect neither...

You can do it like this:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BoxBlurEffect1.AnimateFloat('BlurAmount', 10, 1);
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BoxBlurEffect1.AnimateFloat('BlurAmount', 0, 1);
end;
```

Without TFloatAnimation:

```
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.Point = '(264,192)'
    Width = 80.000000000000000000
    Height = 22.000000000000000000
    OnMouseEnter = Button1MouseEnter
    OnMouseLeave = Button1MouseLeave
    TabOrder = 1
    StaysPressed = False
    IsPressed = False
    Text = 'Button1'
    object BoxBlurEffect1: TBoxBlurEffect
      BlurAmount = 0.009999999776482582
    end
  end
```

Comment: Is it a bug in trigger or i don't know how to use it properly

Comment: thanks it works ; but what i thought was firemonkey will be smart enough to develop animation without a single line of code ; so we can have separate GUI designers

Comment: Not sure... but I think the trigger are checked/forwarded for an animation/effect to only ONE sublevel... so, the Parent of the effect detect the mouse.. forward it to the effect and the effect forgets to forward it to its child... (but as I said.. not sure.. just my guess...)